# MySQL Workbench can't find ODBC Data Source Name for PostgreSQL Driver

Tags: mysql, postgresql, heroku, odbc, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to run a migration from a Heroku PostgreSQL db using Workbench. I'm trying to connect with an ODBC connector.

I can connect fine using the ODBC Administrator. However, using the same info, Workbench tells me it can't find the Data Source Name. Am I missing something? I would expect that the PostgreSQL driver is properly installed if ODBC admin can connect without issue.

[image]

Comment: What's the bit-ness of your MySQL Workbench? It looks like your ODBC Driver is 32-bit. If there's an architecture difference, the PostgreSQL driver/DSN won't show up.

Comment: I think you just need to change Driver from "PostgresSQL Unicode" to "psqlodbc"

Comment: You can also try different connection method - 'ODBC Data Source'.

Comment: @JerodJohnson That was it. Stupidly, the tutorial I was following told me to only use the 32-bit driver b/c Workbench is 32-bit. Guess that was outdated info.